# How reduce rectangle after I detected faces with opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote code for detecting a face and to crop it. I  want to reduce that rectangle so I just get the face without much noise like hair or ear.

Comment: You can refer to my question. The answer will help.
Of course, it deals with only rectangles.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355738/opencv-2-4-2-code-explaination-face-recognition

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you should only detect faces alone i.e. keep the face cascade file alone (deleting hair and ear ones).

Once rectangles are achieved, you cannot distinguish them any more as they are just rectangles.